# can multiple users log into the Wii U at the same time?

Tags: wii-u

Am I stupid?  I want to play Sega Allstars Racing Transformed with my wife but we can't figure out how to play with separate profiles.  It's either Scott and Scott(2) or Izzy and Izzy(2).

Comment: You can make another account by creating another Mii. You can set the default user under "User Settings" after selecting the Mii on the Wii-U menu. Please consult page 33 of your console's [Operations Manual](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/downloads/wiiu_operations_manual_en.pdf) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you but I think you misunderstood the question :(

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "separate" profiles. You can have 12 [user accounts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwNJvCBNQPQ) per console.

Comment: He's asking how, with multiple users configured on the console, to select different ones for each player in local co-op.  (This is trivial on the PS3 and 360 *if the game supports it*, so that may be the case here.  I don't have a Wii-U though.  Probably should retag with the game if it turns out to be game-specific though.)

Comment: It's not necessarily game specific.  I'm not sure it's possible at all to be logged into the console with two Miis

Comment: I might just sell the dumb thing and buy more Xbox games...

Comment: I know for a fact, that *Wii Sports* and *Wii Sports Resort* both allow for every player to select his or her own Mii. Considering those two games, I conclude that this problem **is** game specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. I've wondered this for myself for Injustice: Gods Among Us and Skylanders Giants, but it would appear only one user can be logged in at a time, which is a really weird option in my opinion. It's probably because save files are tied to the user account, and the way they have it set up, it might do some funky stuff if both users are trying to access their save files at the same time.