# Can a 2nd driver in a Mario Kart 8 "vs" race select a User Mii?

Tags: mario-kart-8

When playing a 2-player "vs" race in Mario Kart 8, the highlights reel (which can be viewed in the "MKTV"/"MarioKart TV" section from the main menu) identifies the first player by the name of their "User Mii", which is the user who was selected when the Wii U was powered on. However, the second user is identified by the character name (e.g. "Mario"). Is there any way for the second player to select a "User Mii" when joining a "vs" race?

Looking in the [manual (also available online)](https://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/downloads/games_8/emanuals/wii_u_6/mario_kart_8/ElectronicManual_WiiU_MarioKart8_EN.pdf) (section 6, "Save data"), it says that saved data is associated with the User Mii that is selected when the Wii U is turned on, but it doesn't make any mention of multiplayer races. The vs/battle section of the manual makes no reference to User Miis. So it sounds like you can't, but that feels like a frustratingly inconsistent feature. Although I guess it doesn't save ghost data and other stats during "vs" races, so perhaps there isn't much lost.

So can you select a user per player/driver in local multiplayer mode? Or just for the first player?

EDIT: [A comment on another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97301/can-multiple-users-log-into-the-wii-u-at-the-same-time?rq=1#comment164384_97301) suggests that in some games this is possible, but in others it is not. From what I've seen in-game, it looks like it is not possible in MK. Is there anyone who can confirm that for me?

Comment: No, I think it's a game-specific feature. You can only select your Mii as a driver.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking what I think your asking, then yes, players 2-4 can choose to play as their Mii Character if they wish, by selecting them like every other character in the game, but you can't select more than 1 account.

Comment: They can select a driver like the other players, but I'm asking about the Mii account that the saved data & previous race times get saved against. You select one Mii when starting the Wii up (before loading any games), and youc an only select one. When in Mario Karts highlights reel, that Mii shows up as being assigned to player 1. I haven't seen any chance for other players to select a Mii/account.

Comment: You can't select more than 1 account to play at one time.

Comment: YoshiLikes, add that comment as an answer & I'll accept it